# Bash command to remove leading zeros from all file names

Tags: bash, sed, file-rename

I have a directory with a bunch of files with names like:

```
001234.jpg
001235.jpg
004729342.jpg
```

I want to remove the leading zeros from all file names, so I'd be left with:

```
1234.jpg
1235.jpg
4729342.jpg
```

I've been trying different configurations of sed, but I can't find the proper syntax.  Is there an easy way to list all files in the directory, pipe it through sed, and either move or copy them to the new file name without the leading zeros?

Comment: Note: this will make sorting more difficult.

Comment: With GNU coreutils, `ls -v` will sort numbers naturally (using the Glibc extensions `versionsort(3)/strverscmp(3)`).  But yes, in general, changing the numeric portions of the filenames to no longer line up by length does change normal collation order.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
for FILE in `ls`; do mv $FILE `echo $FILE | sed -e 's:^0*::'`; done
```

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) use `ls` like this. Do it this way: `for FILE in *`

Comment: this is a bad example. first using ls, and then never quote your variables

Comment: I don't see any problem with using ls. You can substitute it for the find command suggested below or any other command.

Since it works I don't really see what your justifications are other than stylistic, which when it comes to one line shell scripts seems a little pointless.

Comment: * will do the right thing, `ls` sometimes will not (for example if a file has a space in its name, this script will not work).

Comment: My experience has not shown that sort of behaviour. If specifying the list myself the items will need to be separated by a line break.

Answer (score 13):

`sed` by itself is the wrong tool for this: you need to use some shell scripting as well.

Check [Rename multiple files with Linux](http://www.go2linux.org/rename-bulk-files-with-linux-console-command) page for some ideas. One of the ideas suggested is to use the `rename` perl script:

```
rename 's/^0*//' *.jpg
```

Comment: I love that command, but unfortunately it's not installed on every system :(.

Comment: @BryanH: ?? This is not Wikipedia, so I'm not sure of the reason for your xkcd cartoon. The point I think I was trying to make (I guess - this was about 18 months ago) was that sed itself isn't able to rename files - you would need some extra scripting to go with it.

Comment: Can confirm this works with the `rename` tool installed from brew (Mac).

Comment: `prename` on Fedora (38).

Answer (score 8):

In Bash, which is likely to be your default login shell, no external commands are necessary.

```
shopt -s extglob
for i in 0*[^0]; do mv "$i" "${i##*(0)}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sed`, e.g.:

```
sed -e 's:^0*::'
```

Complete loop:

```
for f in `ls`; do
   mv $f $(echo $f | sed -e 's:^0*::')
done
```

Comment: This is probably good enough for George's situation, but in a different environment one might wish to handle the special case where the filename is all zeroes.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use `for f in \`ls\`` instead of the much safer and more efficient `for f in *`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most elegant but it will work.

```
for i in 0*
do
mv "${i}" "`expr "${i}" : '0*\(.*\)'`"
done
```

Comment: Your formatting needs work. Use 4 spaces before 'for' to make the whole line a coded section.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know sed at all but you can get a listing by using `find`:

`find -type f -name *.jpg`

so with the other answer it might look like

`find . -type f -name *.jpg | sed -e 's:^0*::'`

but i dont know if that sed command holds up or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that doesn't require `sed`:

```
for x in *.jpg ; do let num="10#${x%%.jpg}"; mv $x ${num}.jpg ;  done
```

Note that this ONLY works when the filenames are all numbers.  You could also remove the leading zeros using the shell:

```
for a in *.jpg ; do dest=${a/*(0)/} ; mv $a $dest ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash shell you can do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in 0*.jpg
do
   echo mv "$file" "${file##*0}"
done
```