# Remove zeros inside file name

Tags: linux, bash, rename, mv

I have this file name

1006_12_000123123_000023126.data

and I want this file name. I have arround 300000 files.

1006_12_123123_23126.png

I tried som of these solution, but they are for filename like 00002323.jpg

[Bash command to remove leading zeros from all file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074687/linux-command-to-remove-leading-zeros-from-a-file-name)

I can use mv to rename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
for original_name in *.data; do
    # determine new file name from original:
    # remove zeroes and change extension.
    new_name=$(echo "$original_name" | sed -e 's/_0*/_/g' -e s'/.data$/.png/')
    mv "$original_name" "$new_name"
done
```

Comment: good solution, but I wil need this in loop like

`for file in *_*_*_*.data
do
    mv  "${file}" "${file/.data/.png}"
done
`

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer to loop over multiple files. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
ls * | sed -e 'p;s/_0*/_/g' | xargs -n2 mv
```

Comment: Watch out, it will loop over all files in the current directory and remove the zeroes in their names

Comment: it returns error

-sh: /bin/ls: Argument list too long

Comment: this is not encouraged too. `ls` is a bad tool to start with when dealing with file names. the correct way is `*` or `find . -print0 | xargs -0` or `find . -exec` pattern.